# how to create a hotspot with captive portal capbility on android phone

Tags: android, wifi

I want to create a WiFi hotspot in my phone with captive portal capability. Anyone know how to to it? It seems that the default hotspot doesn't support captive portal. If the solution needs other software, please tell me. Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you found any solution? Here is some solution - https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/fake-captive-portal-with-android-phone-0167030/